# Trouble Reading json Data from hasoffer API

Tags: php, json

Trying to read json Data and I can't get it to work correctly with the following code:

```
$apiurl = "https://api.hasoffers.com/Apiv3/json?NetworkId=REDACTED&Target=Affiliate_Report&Method=getStats&api_key=REDACTED&fields%5B%5D=Stat.conversions&fields%5B%5D=Stat.unique_clicks&fields%5B%5D=Stat.payout&filters%5BStat.date%5D%5Bconditional%5D=LESS_THAN&filters%5BStat.date%5D%5Bvalues%5D=2016-02-21&filters%5BStat.date%5D%5Bconditional%5D=GREATER_THAN&filters%5BStat.date%5D%5Bvalues%5D=2016-02-21";


$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($apiurl), true);

foreach($data['response']['data'] as $dataline) {

    echo "Conversions: {$dataline['Stat']['conversions']} Payout: {$dataline['Stat']['payout']}";

}
```

The query is generating the following json return, I just can't figure out how to read the stats correctly (it's also looping through 7 lines in the foreach which also makes no sense to me):

> {"request":{"Target":"Affiliate_Report","Format":"json","Service":"HasOffers","Version":"2","NetworkId":"REDACTED","Method":"getStats","api_key":"REDACTED","fields":["Stat.conversions","Stat.unique_clicks","Stat.payout"],"filters":{"Stat.date":{"conditional":"GREATER_THAN","values":"2016-02-21"}},"__gaTune":"GA1.2.1289716345.1455904273","__utma":"267117079.1377304869.1455903853.1455904273.1455904273.1","__utmc":"267117079","__utmz":"267117079.1455904273.1.1.utmcsr=developers.hasoffers.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/","_biz_uid":"1742fd1f613440a4cfbb5a510d1d7def","_biz_nA":"1","_biz_pendingA":"[]","_hp2_id_1318563364":"5257773084071598.0276720083.0714677778","_ga":"GA1.2.1377304869.1455903853"},"response":{"status":1,"httpStatus":200,"data":{"page":1,"current":50,"count":1,"pageCount":1,"data":[{"Stat":{"conversions":"1000","unique_clicks":"1000","payout":"1000.000000"}}],"dbSource":"branddb"},"errors":[],"errorMessage":null}}

Comment: it is invalid json. When in doubt, just copy-paste to one of many sites like [json lint](http://jsonlint.com).

Comment: To clarify, those are numbers that I did not want to make public, they're not returning as text I accidentally removed the quotes when I redacted the numbers, I will edit for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually thank you that site helped a lot realized there was a second array also labeled "data" under the first "data" array so I needed to change it to:

$data['response']['data']['data'] as $dataline

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON is exactly that you have posted, it is unvalid JSON, as per the comments.

The invalid part is the `REDACTED` words without double-quote.

To bypass this error, you can try in this way:

```
$data = file_get_contents( $apiurl );
$data = preg_replace( '/:REDACTED(?=\W)/', ':"REDACTED"', $data );

$json = json_decode( $data, True );
```

This will works on example above, but please note that is a trick, and it **can not work** if some JSON field has a **value** like "sometext:REDACTED,sometext": it is improbable, but not impossible.